# Building a View or Panel(?) from an existing node and customize path and breadcrumb

Tags: views, panels

I have this requirement I don't know how to approach.
The site's taxonomy is used in a hierachical way.

I have a `Conference` content type and the breadcrumbs and url's follow this pattern:

`home/conferences/conference-type/continent/conf-title` where `conference-type` and `continent` are taxonomy terms

A `Conference` has an image gallery contained in an `Image field`, which is **not** visible on the Conference page itself but to a dedicated page located to    `home/resources/gallery/conference-type/continent/conference-name`

My question is how do I build this page dynamically from the conference node's content ?

I could use a view or a panel and pass the nid contextual filter, but then:

- How do I build the path/breadcrumb from the nid passed as argument?
- How do I make sure the view is invoked on this specific path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base url of the view would be `home/resources/gallery/%/%/%` this would ensure that the view is invoked only when all three arguments are present.

and Rather than sending one argument to the view you would be seinding three arguments.

1. Conference Type - The taxonomy term
2. Continent - The Taxonomy term
3. conference-name

Since your content would have all three condition to be true you would get the required url. Other wise you can set it to show a page not found or may do some other things as you want.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine when I use home/resources/gallery/5/16 (5=term id, 16=termid), but not with normal urls home/resources/gallery/myterm/nodetitle . Do you have an idea?

Comment: you can pass the taxonomy term name instead of the id as the contextual filter